# Is this particular question a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

I have originally closed this question ["Round off to the nearest 0.05 C++"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26001887/round-off-to-the-nearest-0-05-c) as duplicate of ["Round a float to a given precision"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208971/round-a-float-to-a-given-precision) with my ability to short cut close duplicates.

The OP started a long and lamenting rant in comments in turn, that the Q&A mentioned as the dupe, don't address their concerns, don't work, etc. But without any real improvement of the question (not even in the comments), towards what's actually their problem.

Being massively annoyed by the OP's comments (that also had some ad hominem tendencies), I finally decided to retract my duplicate close vote, and summarized up an answer from what I understood from OP's question, and how this would be solved by the given code from the dupe.

My question is:
**Should I have better left this question closed?**

I did't see an alternative way, to make it clear for the OP, their question actually is a duplicate of the other one (comments don't fit very well for this), and I also disliked to be left abandoned with this critique.

<sub>If anyone else also thinks, the post in question is a dupe, don't hesitate to close it please!</sub>

---

**Finally** [@juanchopanza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661519/juanchopanza) (Cheeers!!) showed mercy, and drew the curtain over that little *Punch & Judy show*!

Comment: That user's got a real great attitude: "Explain me now....Now you are responsible"

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot May be that's a big failure, but if s.o. calls me responsible, I tend to feel being so ;-) ...

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot "Now you are responsible" is a common misuse of "to be" and misunderstanding of "responsible" in non-native English speakers I've seen quite a lot.  It's probably not attitude, he/she just doesn't quite know the right words.

Comment: @Izkata Sorry, don't buy it. I've seen this attitude with plenty of native English speakers as well. The comment thread is now deleted, but there was a clear, consistent tone of "You must serve me." No please, no thank you, only "do it, because I said so."

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I should have been saving a screenshot :P ...

Comment: It's not like it would make any more sense or be any less rude if you replaced it with "to be": "Explain me now...Now you are to be"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your answer is:

**Yes!**

Comment: Actually I couldn't see a better way to make the OP aware that their question _really is_ a duplicate. Comments don't format well for this, and I didn't want to just let it begone.

Comment: Uh, anyone else dare to (re-)close that question now?

Answer (score -2):

**Yes to the question body, No to the question title...  Sorta**

The question titles are not duplicates of each other, but what is described in the question bodies are.

For example, rounding `11.2125` to the nearest `0.05` is actually `11.20`, *not* `11.21` or `11.22`.  However, the examples given in the body do not show this behavior.

The problem is that "precision" is a slightly different concept.  If you were rounding `11.2125` to a *precision* of 2 decimals, then you'd get `11.21` or `11.22`, depending if you rounded up or down.

So reading the one it's marked a duplicate of - I think that question has the wrong title.  The accepted answer over there also doesn't explain it very well, but just sticks a hardcoded `5` in their round function, making it easy to miss (as I did initially).

Comment: The titles don't necessarily need to match, to identify duplicate questions IMHO.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I agree (and the header added says "already has an answer", so it's rather explicit), I'm just trying to point out why it might not be easy to see.  It took me the 10 minutes to type this up, going back and forth to ensure I wasn't missing something, before I even noticed that the accepted answer _does_ answer what's in the new question's title.  You have to understand what that one is doing before seeing it is a duplicate, because nothing is actually explained on it.