# Do some posters fish for duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

In other words, are some posters too lazy to search so they post a question knowing / hoping that someone will close their question as a duplicate and in doing so give them the link to something they wanted in the first place?

Comment: Probably, but what would you do with that information?

Comment: I don't know that anyone, other than a person with intense interest in sociology or psychology, could do anything with the information. It was just something that occurred to me as I marked some questions as duplicates over the past couple of days where the poster appeared to be intelligent enough to know that there would be dupes of the question they asked.

Comment: I have *started* typing up questions in the hope that the search would pop up the solution before I actually finished. It's worked on quite a few occasions.

Comment: @ChrisF Oh yeah; that happens to me 19/20 of the time I have considered posting a question. I think I even once made a Meta post asking if it seemed to people that search worked better than the main search. (the consensus was yes; it does)

Comment: Something that often occurs to me about someone being 'lazy'; often, it seems like those people are lazy because they want a fast answer. It usually strikes me that a faster answer would be better found by searching, than waiting for someone to come up with a new answer.

Comment: I think that a lot of folks tend to ignore the suggested list of questions/answers because they think that a.) their question is somehow different and 2.) they never look beyond what they're typing.

Comment: How would this work? If you post a question knowing it's a duplicate, you already know there's a duplicate, so you wouldn't need someone to close your question and provide a link. I'm not sure you could purposefully duplicate in the way you're suggesting.

Comment: They may know there is a duplicate, they just don't want to do the search themselves. I am not suggesting that anything be done about it, it was more of a discussion question.

Comment: The wording of this question suggests that the questioner *knows* (as fact) that a duplicate definitely exists. This, imo, is different to someone who has done a superficial search and not found an exact match to their particular situation. In the latter case, asking a question is akin to "please parse the information out there and tailor it to my particular needs in a good-quality answer that doesn't force me to think hard".

Comment: Personally when I first started using SO I had no idea duplicates even existed. I would ask stuff here because I greatly appreciated the tailored-to-me answers I got, and it was often easier than trying to figure out what it was I needed to Google for and find a decent site with a readable, easy-to-understand answer. I would never do that now that I know the site better, however I can understand many people not realizing that we don't like duplicates. (Also, last I checked SO's search was definitely not ideal, so searching SO for existing questions rarely returned useful results)

Comment: And then there was the recent [DO NOT CLOSE, Not a duplicate!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272009/is-this-particular-question-a-duplicate) rant where the poster *insisted* it wasn't because his numbers were different.

Comment: I fish for duplicates to flag them as duplicates sometimes.  When I'm REALLY bored.

Comment: @AndrewBarber And in some rare situations, neither of those finds a duplicate - but the "Related questions" sidebar that you only get after posting the question does have duplicates...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I've seen a significant increase in the "can you Google this for me" questions.  The kind where simply pasting the title of the question in the Google query box gives the answer on the first page of results.  Usually with SO posts on top.

There's just no incentive for questioners to do this themselves, much easier to let somebody else read through the web pages.  I used to comment "Paste the title of your question in the Google query box and take the first hit".  But that's *verboten* these days.  Can't close them either, that dialog was redesigned to make *me* look stoopid and closing as duplicate just reinforces this awful habit.  So it's just downvote and commiserate over another minute of my life I'll never get back :(

Comment: This is correct. Odd, related note: I frequently find that the *question itself* is among the first results, in those cases! hehe

Comment: ++ [same thing I've done before](https://www.google.com/?q=same%20thing%20I%20have%20done%20before)

Comment: I'm always ready to go the extra mile with such questions and so find a reason of some sort to close-vote.  I have a coin on my desk to choose between 'unclear' and 'too broad' :)

Comment: Of course, what we need is 'OP is a troll, assignment/homework cheat,  vampire, bone-idle deadbeat or just too stupid to use a computer', but I guess that's not gonna happen:(

Comment: @HansPassant Wow... that's a lot of notifications you've been getting! Doing the 'needful'... I deleted the comment you posted just to avoid any minor Meta Effect there.

Comment: "There's just no incentive for questioners to do this themselves" Shouldn't them getting an answer instantly instead of having to wait a couple minutes for someone to respond be enough incentive?

Comment: SO's famously fast response times are not helping to solve this problem.

Comment: This is exactly why people have started using the custom Off-Topic reason...

Comment: If they are lazy, there is a good chance the question can be closed for some other reason.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if many do that *purposefully*. I would think that if they are consciously thinking about duplicates at all, they might do a quick search, first. Often, people who acknowledge being a duplicate, they say that the other post didn't have acceptable answers... though I suppose you *could* consider those to be doing what you wonder, here.

More often, though; I think they just don't think about it at all.

Comment: closed as duplicate is same as closed for any other reason , in terms of question ban, right?

Comment: I would think so @lostsock, but some don't care. They'd just creat a new account for the next batch of questions.

Comment: @lostsock As Stack Exchange doesn't share the specifics, we can't know for sure, of course; but I know if I were creating that algo, I would probably do something like give dupes slightly less weight than other closes, but still count them.

Comment: @lostsock note that the question ban is changing to be a harsher rate limiting rather than a complete *ban* (that doesn't mean that people will not create new accounts to try to get around them though). Thus, my anecdotal evidence seems to suggest it is *downvoted* closes that trigger the ban. Just having a question closed as a dup isn't sufficient for the algorithm (highly voted opinion and broad don't seem to trigger it either). As dups are also protected from the 9 day delete script, its also harder to have *deleted* closed, down voted questions with dups.

Comment: @MichaelT That's actually a good point to mention, too; down voted posts which are closed seem to have more weight (even if "more" simply means, "more than zero"!)

Comment: It [appears that duplicates count the same](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236947/159251), @lostsock, but in my opinion they shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I draft my question like a "dress rehearsal" in hopes of either:

- figuring out the answer myself as a result of drafting the question
- being referred to the closest duplicate(s) via Stack's related/duplicate algorithm

I've found that forming a question is easily the best way to find the best related questions on SO, much more so than doing a tag/keyword search.

Not to put words in your mouth, but I suspect you're asking "Should SO do anything about people fishing for duplicates." In my opinion Stack gets it as right as it possibly can -- at some point you have to rely on users to put in the effort of clicking the related link.

Comment: Thank you for not putting words in my mouth :) I *am not* asking that at all, it was just a certain behavior I've noticed in a couple of tags the past couple of weeks where I suspect the rate of fishing might be higher than other tags.

Answer (score -2):

My philosophy is if while entering my question a duplicate does not pop up, I post it, even if I suspect that a duplicate may exists.

My thought pattern, which has proven true, is that the community should decide whether the question truly is a duplicate. In some cases, it is, but I have also seen quite a few cases where my question had implication other questions didn't and produced completely different and great answers.

Whether or not people do fish for duplicates, we should leave it up to the community to decide.

Comment: And this is why I refuse to use meta, I make what I think is a decent contribution, and I get downvoted with no reason why whatsoever.

Comment: The search for an answer determines if the question is duplicate. No acceptable answer implies a unique question, and the question should be worded as such. You ought to already have the opinion that your question is unique prior to posting it.